# How to assign a Line Number from a text file to a variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to print the variable 'Number' But it come up with a error.

'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple'

I dont understand? What is a tuple and how could i fix this problem? 
How do i assign a line number in a text file to a variable?

```
def CheckDatabase():
    print ("====Check Database===== \nA)Would you like to check details? \nB)Check if they are a member?")
    TC = input(": ")
    if TC == "A" or TC == "a":
        NameDetail = input ("Please enter the name you would like to check the details of.\nThis will only work if they are a member\n: ")
        with open('Name.txt') as ND:
            for number, line in enumerate(ND, 1):
                if (str(NameDetail)) in line:
                    Number = number, line in enumerate(ND, 1)
                    print ("\nName = ", NameDetail)

                    A = open("Address.txt", "r")
                    AData =[line.rstrip() for line in A.readlines()]
                    print ("Address = ",(AData[Number]))

                    HN = open("Home Number.txt", "r")
                    HNData =[line.rstrip() for line in HN.readlines()]
                    print ("Home Number = ",(HNData[Number]))

                    MN = open("Mobile Number.txt", "r")
                    MNData =[line.rstrip() for line in MN.readlines()]
                    print ("Mobile Number = ",(MNData[Number]))

                    EAS = open("Email Address.txt", "r")
                    EAData =[line.rstrip() for line in EAS.readlines()]
                    print ("Email Address = ",(EAData[Number]))

                    MDND = open("Email Address.txt", "r")
                    MDNData =[line.rstrip() for line in MDND.readlines()]
                    print ("Medical/Dietry Needs = ",(MDNData[Number]))


                else:
                    print ("Person not found!")
```

**EDIT:**

```
import time

def AddToDatabase():
    print ("\nYou are adding to the Database. \nA)Continue \nB)Go Back")
    ATD = input(": ")
    if ATD == "A" or ATD == "a":

        Name = input("\nEnter Name of Member [First Name and Surname]: ")
        with open("Name.txt", "a") as N:
            N.write("\n{}".format(Name))
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("\nAdding...")
        time.sleep(1)

        print ("\nEnter Address of "+Name+" all on one line")
        print ("In format [Include Commas]")
        print ("\nRoad name with house number [e.g. 1 Morgan Way], Borough [e.g Harrow], City [e.g London], Postcode [e.g. HA5 2EF]")
        Address = input("\n: ")
        with open("Address.txt", "a") as A:
            A.write("\n{}".format(Address))
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("\nAdding...")
        time.sleep(1)

        Home_Number = input("\nEnter Home Number of "+Name+": ")
        with open("Home Number.txt", "a") as HN:
            HN.write("\n{}".format(Home_Number))
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("\nAdding...")
        time.sleep(1)

        Mobile_Number = input ("\nEnter Mobile Number of "+Name+": ")
        with open("Mobile Number.txt", "a") as MN:
            MN.write("\n{}".format(Mobile_Number))
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("\nAdding...")
        time.sleep(1)

        Email_Address = input ("\nEnter Email Address of "+Name+": ")
        with open("Email Address.txt", "a") as EA:
            EA.write("\n{}".format(Email_Address))
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("\nAdding...")
        time.sleep(1)

        Dietry_Needs = input("\nEnter Medical/Dietry Needs of "+Name+": ")
        with open("Medical Dietry Needs.txt", "a") as MDN:
            MDN.write("\n{}".format(Dietry_Needs))
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("\nAdding...")
        time.sleep(1)

        print ("All information for "+Name+" has been added. Redirecting Back To Main...")
        time.sleep(5)
        Main()

    elif ATD == "B" or ATD == "b":
        Main()

def CheckDatabase():
    print ("====Check Database===== \nA)Would you like to check details? \nB)Check if they are a member?")
    TC = input(": ")
    if TC == "A" or TC == "a":
        NameDetail = input ("Please enter the name you would like to check the details of.\nThis will only work if they are a member\n: ")
        with open('Name.txt') as ND:
            for number, line in enumerate(ND, 1):
                if (str(NameDetail)) in line:
                    Number, junk = number, line in enumerate(ND, 1)
                    print ("\nName = ", NameDetail)

                    A = open("Address.txt", "r")
                    AData =[line.rstrip() for line in A.readlines()]
                    print ("Address = ",(AData[number]))

                    HN = open("Home Number.txt", "r")
                    HNData =[line.rstrip() for line in HN.readlines()]
                    print ("Home Number = ",(HNData[Number]))

                    MN = open("Mobile Number.txt", "r")
                    MNData =[line.rstrip() for line in MN.readlines()]
                    print ("Mobile Number = ",(MNData[Number]))

                    EAS = open("Email Address.txt", "r")
                    EAData =[line.rstrip() for line in EAS.readlines()]
                    print ("Email Address = ",(EAData[Number]))

                    MDND = open("Email Address.txt", "r")
                    MDNData =[line.rstrip() for line in MDND.readlines()]
                    print ("Medical/Dietry Needs = ",(MDNData[Number]))


                else:
                    print ("Person not found!")

    elif TC == "B" or TC == "b":
        NameChoice = input("Enter persons name: ")
        with open('Name.txt') as NAME:
            for number, line in enumerate(NAME, 1):
                if (str(NameChoice)) in line:
                    print (NameChoice)
                    print ("is a member")
                else:
                    print ("Not a member!")


def Main():
    print ("\nSVA of UK Database")
    while True:
        print ("\nA)Check Database \nB)Add to Database \nC)Exit Program")
        choice = input(": ")

        if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
            CheckDatabase()

        elif choice == "B" or choice == "b":
            AddToDatabase()

        elif choice == "C" or choice == "c":
            break

        else:
            print ("Invalid Input")
            Main()

Main()
```

**EDIT 2:**
Name.txt :

```
Sagar Bharadia
```

Address.txt

```
8 John Road
```

Home Number.txt

```
02089563524
```

Mobile Number.txt

```
02045745854
```

Medical Dietry Needs.txt

```
None
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
SVA of UK Database

A)Check Database 
B)Add to Database 
C)Exit Program
: A
====Check Database===== 
A)Would you like to check details? 
B)Check if they are a member?
: A
Please enter the name you would like to check the details of.
This will only work if they are a member
: Sagar Bharadia

Name =  Sagar Bharadia
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\SVA UK PROGRAM\SVA of UK.py", line 126, in <module>
    Main()
  File "H:\SVA UK PROGRAM\SVA of UK.py", line 114, in Main
    CheckDatabase()
  File "H:\SVA UK PROGRAM\SVA of UK.py", line 74, in CheckDatabase
    print ("Address = ",(AData[Number]))
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback. But there is no need to set `Number = number, line ...` (which makes it a tuple); you already have the line number, just use `number`.

Comment: Is this the entire code?

Comment: I am able to paste the entire code if it would help :) The problem had only occured in this section though which is why i only printed this subroutine

Comment: @PythonBeginner Yes, paste the entire code.

Comment: I have provided full code for you to see @2rs2ts

Comment: @PythonBeginner Show us also the input file you are using.

Comment: I am sorry to ask if what you are asking is obvious. But what is a input file? @2rs2ts

Comment: @PythonBeginner Show us the contents of `Name.txt`, `Address.txt` et cetera. We need to see input and expected output.

Comment: Ok i will edit the post now @2rs2ts

Comment: Those are obviously not the entire contents of your files. I suggest you check `len(AData)` and the other lengths of the lists you construct from your files. Also, make sure you `.close()` the files.

Comment: @2rs2ts I have copied my result after print the length of AData and it is 1.

Comment: I have done the same with the others and it comes with the result of '1' aswell. @2rs2ts

Comment: @PythonBeginner Got it. You still should be careful with your files, but I realized the problem and have edited my answer accordingly. The problem is that you are confusing when to start your list indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `Number` as a tuple when you do `Number = number, line in enumerate(ND, 1)`. You already created `number, line in enumerate(ND, 1)` with your `for` loop anyway. Why not just use that? i.e. `AData[number]`.

Just using an example, this is what essentially what you are setting `Number` to:

```
>>> for x, y in enumerate([1,2,3], 1):
        print x, y in enumerate([1,2,3], 1)


1 False
2 False
3 False
```

It is a tuple containing the `number` from your `for` loop, and the value of `line in enumerate(ND, 1)` (a boolean expression, either it's in there or it's not).

You also have several other problems:

- You start `number` at `1` instead of `0` by providing the `1` to `enumerate`. In python, list indices start at `0`. So if the length of a list is `1` then sub-indexing at `[1]` is actually out of bounds. You should be doing `enumerate(ND)` instead to start at `0`.
- You need to `.close()` your files that you `open()`, or use `with`/`as` like you do with your first file.
- You are opening `Email Address.txt` twice... did you mean to do that?

Comment: It comes up with the error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @PythonBeginner That's an entirely different problem you have with the contents of `AData` and the other lines in your file and not part of the code you posted.

Comment: @PythonBeginner My guess is that your have more lines in `Name.txt` than in your other text file(s). Hence the `IndexError` (`number` is bigger than `len(AData)`.)

Comment: Ok ill delete all other lines than the ones needed in the text files. I have deleted the lines to leave only the top ones and the error still appears. @2rs2ts It is really confusing me now as to what the problem could be

Comment: No i did not mean to open Email Address.txt twice thanks for pointing that out. I will switch to one and make it with so it automatically closes @2rs2ts

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
Number = number, line in enumerate(ND, 1)
```

You are assigning two values to Number -- this produces a tuple.

You could do something like this:

```
Number, junk = number, line in enumerate(ND, 1)
```

This would result in Number being a single value, no longer a tuple.

Comment: I get the same error as when i tried @2rs2ts suggestion. IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Your revised code still has this line: `Number = number, line in enumerate(ND, 1)`, which means again, Number is a tuple and not an integer, therefore cannot be a list index.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are a kind of a "list". See doc on:

http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html

You are probably assigning 2 or more values for the var Number